# creating viewport causes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string Error

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, mobile-website

I want to create an instance of my viewport form the app.js file using this line of code :

```
 Ext.create('myapp.view.Viewport')
```

but i keep getting this error in my console log

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: This should be a syntax error of Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a thing to ask before:

```
Ext.create('myapp.view.Viewport')
```

did u miss the ; at the end?

If you didn't miss it then i can tell you that

```
Ext.create('myapp.view.Viewport');
```

works correct in my `app.js` using MVC pattern for extjs.

The only things i could suggest is to verify if the files are into the correct directory MVC except to find.